# How to rename the key of a JSON Response dynamically in Retrofit2 Android

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin, retrofit

I have a JSON response like this:

```
    {
        "AED_BDT": 23.100486
    }
```

But the key changes according to my query like if my query is **USD_BDT**, then it will give response like this:

```
 {
        "USD_BDT": 23.100486
 }
```

So,that means I need to change the **JSON** key according to my query. But I couldn't find any solution on how to do this.

I tried by converting the response body into String and then replaced the Key according to my query, but this is not working..

This is my model class:

```
data class ResponseCurrencyConvert(
    val USD_BDT: Double
)
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
val params = HashMap<String,String>()
        params["compact"]="ultra"
        params["apiKey"]= API_KEY
        params["q"]="${currencyFrom}_${currencyTo}"//getting specific currencies and then setting them as query,i.e:USD_BDT
        message(TAG,"Query: ${params["q"]}")
        prefManager.query=params["q"]!!

        //calling the API
        apiServices.convertCurrency(params).enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseCurrencyConvert>{
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseCurrencyConvert>, t: Throwable) {
                message(TAG,"onFailure: ${t.localizedMessage}")
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseCurrencyConvert>, response: Response<ResponseCurrencyConvert>) {
               message(TAG,"onResponse Code: ${response.code()}")
               message(TAG,"onResponse Body: ${Gson().toJson(response.body())}")

                val json = Gson().toJson(response.body())//converting the response as string
                val oldValue = "USD_BDT"//the key which was in my model class
                val newValue=params["q"]// the new key which is my query
                val output = json.replace(oldValue,newValue!!,false) // replacing the default query with my query
                val newResponse = Gson().fromJson(output,ResponseCurrencyConvert::class.java)//again converting the new replaced string to json

                    if (response.isSuccessful){

                    message(TAG,"Output: $output")
                    message(TAG,"onResponse Result: ${newResponse?.USD_BDT}")
                    message(TAG,"onResponse newResult: ${newResponse.USD_BDT}")
                    rate= newResponse?.USD_BDT//getting the value; this is returning 0 every time expect when my query is USD_BDT
```

I commented everything that I did on the code, please read that carefully. Your help is highly appreciated..

Comment: parse this as a HashMap and then pull keys and values using EntrySet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to do that is maintaining the 2 different keys, which is the most simple and effective.

Another way to accomplish this is changing the Response type to string. When you get the response you change the JSON string, changing the key name and then use GSON to manually convert from JSON to Object.

Maybe it can be done also with a Custom Json Converter, but I don't think is worth.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I am trying this, but is it possible to change the key by using Interceptor? Because, generally interceptor is used for intercepting the response value using the keys.. I am very confused :(

Comment: @SoumikBhattacharjee Ok, maybe the Interceptor is not a good solution, I've added two more solutions, please take a look at the edited reply.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time, I will try this and will let you know how it goes

Comment: Yes, finally your second solution worked, But as my response was a object so changing its type to String encountered an error, but going by your idea i change the response type to 'Any' and then converted the response as a String and got what i was looking for.. Thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 1):

Keys are defined from the server only I guess

The best way you can do is like keep both keys and make it nullable

else you have an alternate name in JSON parsing

Comment: agree here, use 2 fields and you can use a property or function to get one value or the other checking which one is not null

Comment: Simple way
```{
        "Currency" : "USD_BDT"
        "USD_BDT": 23.100486,
        "AED_BDT": null
      }```

The server will only tell you which key you need to parse and based on that parse that key only

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion, but these two are used for example only, In real I have a total of 152 currencies, and for every conversion the keys are different, so it would be very difficult to check all those.

Answer (score 0):

If the key changes for every other response, I would suggest using `HashMap<String, String>`. Instead of mapping directly to String value which changes dynamically using `HashMap` would solve your issue.

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'll definitely let you know